# Real time permission in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native . I want to ask real time permission for Location .Please help me how to take Real Time Permission in react native.

Comment: Are you using expo ?

Comment: No I am testing in real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best avoid libraries for permission check**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Important - include the above code line in your manifest file**

```
 import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native';

  componentDidMount() {
       if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
              this.requestLocationPermission(); // function call
         }
   }
```

Below `code` contains `function` body.

```
  async requestLocationPermission() {
     try {
       const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === true) 
       {
          // WHAT TODO WHEN PERMISSION IS GRANTED
       } else {
         // WHAT TODO WHEN PERMISSION IS NOT GRANTED
      }
    } catch (err) {
      log(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: where I have to call this method inside render()?

Comment: updated..it was a platform check function it is really not necessary

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this library: [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

react-native-permissions might be overkill if you only need access to location. React Native seems to have its own API for that : [RN geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation#requestauthorization)

```
import {geolocation } from "react-native";

// ...

geolocation.requestAuthorization()
```

Permission required on iOS depends on which keys you have in your plist. For android, I guess you have nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull geolocation is depreciated now. You better use Amal' solution.

```
import {geolocation } from "react-native";
```