# React Native geolocation permissions callback

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Im having a hard time with permissions and getting the current location properly on RN.

All i'm really trying to do is get a callback when the permission is denied or granted so i can respectively request my current location. Im requesting the permission using:

`geolocation.requestAuthorization();`

which doesnt return a promise or accept a callback so the only real way for me to know wether permissions are granted or not is to call repeatedly

`geolocation.getCurrentPosition();`

and examine its contents

This feels a little hamfisted as `setInterval` is barely ever the answer so im out looking for a better approach.

Comment: checkout my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701561/real-time-permission-in-react-native/52716652#52716652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Some thing like this and it works for me.

```js
 (async () => {
       { try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            'title': 'Your App',
            'message': 'Allow app to access your location '
          }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                console.log(position);
               Geocoder.geocodePosition({lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude})
               .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                  locationResult: res[0].formattedAddress
                });
            })
            },
            (error) => {
                // See error code charts below.
                console.log(error.code, error.message);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
        );
        } else {
          alert("Location permission denied");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("No Access  to location" + err);
      }
    }
  })();
```

The locationResult in the state will hold the address details.